# Attach process stderr in the case of an error

Tags: testing, logging, robotframework, stderr

I am running a bunch of integration tests on a single executable. The program signals an error condition by its return code and might print some (diverse but still useful) output to stderr.

I am currently using the process library as follows:

```
         ${result} =         Run Process        ${prog}        ${src}
         Should Be Equal As Integers    ${result.rc}    0
```

This works fine in the case of succeeding tests, but in the case of errors it does not yield any meaningful information. Is there a way to attach the stderr stream to the log file in the case of failing tests? I am reluctant to add in for every test case to not clutter the log file, but if that is the only option, I would appreciate a hint on how to do this the orthodox way as well.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at [Process documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html), you can redirect `stderr`to a file:

**Standard output and error streams**

By default processes are run so that their standard output and standard error streams are kept in the memory. This works fine normally, but if there is a lot of output, the output buffers may get full and the program can hang. 
Additionally on Jython, everything written to these in-memory buffers can be lost if the process is terminated.
To avoid the above mentioned problems, it is possible to use stdout and stderr arguments to specify files on the file system where to redirect the outputs. This can also be useful if other processes or other keywords need to read or manipulate the outputs somehow.
Given stdout and stderr paths are relative to the current working directory. Forward slashes in the given paths are automatically converted to backslashes on Windows.
As a special feature, it is possible to redirect the standard error to the standard output by using stderr=STDOUT.
Regardless are outputs redirected to files or not, they are accessible through the result object returned when the process ends. Commands are expected to write outputs using the console encoding, but output encoding can be configured using the output_encoding argument if needed.

Examples:

```
${result} = Run Process program stdout=${TEMPDIR}/stdout.txt    stderr=${TEMPDIR}/stderr.txt
Log Many    stdout: ${result.stdout}    stderr: ${result.stderr}        
${result} = Run Process program stderr=STDOUT
Log all output: ${result.stdout}
```

Note that the created output files are not automatically removed after the test run. The user is responsible to remove them if needed.